# How do I get SharedPreference to work with Camera.Parameters setPreviewSize

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

How do i get SharedPreference to work for preview size of Android.Camera

My textbox contains the following string: "352, 288"

```
Previewsize = setingPreferences.getString("screensize", "");
parameters.setPreviewSize(parseInt(Previewsize));
```

I get the following compiler error:

> setPreviewSize (int, int ) in parameters cannot be applied to int

I also tried with

```
 parameters.setPreviewSize(getString(Previewsize));
```

but here I get this compiler error:

> cannot resolve method getstring

Comment: add some more code please.

Comment: all the other parameters works fine by using the sharedprefference the same way as i trying here its just my preview size i can't get to work  i think it might be due to it uses 
352, 288 which is not a int a value but a string and preview size doesn't supports strings

Comment: Have you checked with `Log`? What is the value that shared preference return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start out with explaining the two compiler errors you're receiving:

> setPreviewSize (int, int ) in parameters cannot be applied to int

This tells you, that you're trying to parse a single int to the setPreviewSize method, while it actually takes two ints.

> cannot resolve method getString

This simply means there's no method called getString.

If `Previewsize` is your string containing `352,288`, you can perform a String split operation to split the two values into an array with two entries.

```
String previewSize = setingPreferences.getString("screensize", "");
String[] sizes = previewSize.split(",");
parameters.setPreviewSize(Integer.parseInt(sizes[0]), Integer.parseInt(sizes[1]);
```